# Android: Saving image to storage

Tags: java, android, image, save

Currently my application, takes a photo, and put's the data into a ImageView.

```
public void openCamera() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
}
```

Now, i want it to do this: When the user clicks the button 'Save Button' I would like it to save to storage. How would i do this? I have my button set up with an OnClick listener.

```
public void save_btn() {

}
```

Comment: Have you read http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html ?

Comment: Yes, i have but how would i add that to an OnClick Listener

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html there is a button onclick listener example.

Comment: check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html)

Comment: Could anyone provide me the code from here inside an OnClick listener please?   http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath       So when the button is clicked, it runs Save the Full-size Photo part. Thanks

Comment: Accept an answer if you found one helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Hold onto the `Bitmap` somewhere

Step #2: When the button is clicked, fork a background thread, `AsyncTask`, `IntentService`, etc. to do the work

Step #3: In the background thread (or whatever), [call `compress()` on the `Bitmap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29), providing an `OutputStream` on whatever file you want to write to

Comment: For this case (bitmap.compress), would you recommend AsyncTask or IntentService?

Comment: @Jamrelian: Writing out a `Bitmap` should not take a lot of time, so `IntentService` may be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

use Bitmap compress method to store bitmap into the android data storage. and if you want to store full size of image then please use intent.putExtra with file uri or even you can create your own content Provider (Which is my fav).

bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);

http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath

takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String filename = "somename.jpg"; // your filename with path to sdcard
File file = new File(filename);
OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream); // your bitmap
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the code you can save image on sd card :

```
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            File f=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/My Image/");
            f.mkdir();
            String extStorageDirectory = f.toString();
            File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "image.jpg");
            pathOfImage = file.getAbsolutePath();
            try {
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved at "+f.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            try {
                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: is this for onClick?